# Why does placing an antenna far from the wood increase the efficiency of the antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, efficiency, radiation, dielectric

I designed a monopole antenna at 868MHz frequency. I placed wood as the surrounding material. I noticed that placing the antenna far from the wood increases the efficiency of the antenna. Can anyone explain why this increasing distance results in increasing efficiency?

Comment: How far away is it, exactly? Similar question: [Is there a way to reliably measure antenna return loss outside a lab?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/281971)

Comment: What is used to hold the antenna away from the wood?  Your body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wood has an approximate [water content](https://www.wagnermeters.com/moisture-meters/wood-info/acceptable-moisture-levels-wood/#:%7E:text=The%20acceptable%20moisture%20levels%20of,The%20wood%27s%20final%20use.) of about 10%. Water has a dielectric property that is vastly different to air. The dielectric constant of water is about [80 times higher](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/diel.html) than air or a vacuum.

A normal antenna relies on the dielectric constant that immediately surrounds it being that of air or a vacuum. If it isn't then the antenna is detuned; the closer the moisture is, the more the detuning.

And, to add the the problem of the dielectric constant is the fact that moisture trapped in wood is partially conductive so, the electric fields from/to the antenna will be attenuated.

Comment: I learned something here, thanks. Does this mean that humidity in the air can detune an antenna? Are exterior antennae affected in this way at all, with rain and humidity and all?

Comment: @SimonFitch Even in very humid air, less than 2% is water -. the lower *dielectric constant* of air dominates. Water droplets attaching to antenna causes another problem: increased noise due to static charge transfer.

Comment: The OMEGA (defunct VLF navigation system) station I visited had an antenna auto-tuner. Cloud conditions required continuously tuning the antenna system as the antenna was often covered by clouds.