# How to increase efficiency of antenna without moving antenna far from tree?

Tags: rf, antenna, efficiency, radiation, dielectric

I have designed a monopole antenna at 868MHz frequency. Now I would like to attach that antenna to the tree (wood). But, due to [Why does placing an antenna far from the wood increase the efficiency of the antenna?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/593244/why-does-placing-an-antenna-far-from-the-wood-increase-the-efficiency-of-the-ant), antenna efficiency is decreasing.

I would like to know whether is there any way to increase the efficiency without moving antenna far from tree?

Comment: note: the point is not that the tree is made of wood (dried wood has maybe 10% water content by weight) but a live tree, being 50% water.

Comment: Maybe forget about the tree and focus on things that actually matter. Is it a 1/2 wave or 1/4 antenna? Assuming panel mount, how large a ground plane made in metal did you place it on? Did you ground it at all? Where?

Comment: Sai, are we done with this Q and A session now? If so, then I think you are aware of the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can do is make sure that the giant, 50% water in the main body, more even in the foliage, structure that is called "tree" isn't interacting with the electrical field too much.

Distance is the safest bet, but also, making sure the electrical field lines of your "ideal, in vacuum" monopole don't run through the tree certainly helps; so, since a monopole is polarized along its axis, that means you'd want to put it such that the main lobe isn't pointing at the tree, and that means there's only one place that might work – on top of the tree, like a lightning arrestor. This would have the advantage of actually radiating in all directions evenly, which is what you want if you're designing a monopole, right? However, you do not want to mount it there, for lightning reasons, and also, because trees to tend to shake, and also grow.

Considering a 868 MHz quarter-wave monopole is roughly 86 mm in length, the "easy" solution is to mount that small thing away from the stem. No shortcuts. No shortcuts necessary, anyway, all this requires is some form of clamp and a cantilever, which both are things you will need, no matter how or where you mount your monopole.

If you do not actually need an omnidirectional antenna: don't use a monopole, but something with a zero in one direction and gain in some other direction, and point the zero at the stem and the main lobe at where you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

> *I would like to know whether is there any way to increase the
> efficiency without moving antenna far from tree?*

and

> *I have designed a monopole antenna at 868MHz frequency*

Your antenna is a monopole type; therefore it needs a ground-plane. This is because it is an unbalanced antenna (unlike a dipole). So, fix your antenna so that the tree becomes the ground-plane or, if you are worried that it may not act as a reliable ground-plane, then mount an *effective* ground-plane between antenna and tree: -

[image]

Image from [this wiki site on monopole antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopole_antenna).

Notice the three downward facing limbs; they are a common way of making an *effective* ground-plane that "shields" your monopole from the tree below. There are plenty of ways of doing this of course.

However, if you wish that your monopole be firmly placed in the structure of the tree with branches surrounding it then you should rethink your ideas.